# save file in utf-8 without bom

Tags: php, file, utf-8, save

I have a form in Vietnamese and it submits data to a web service. This web service saves that data in a file. But the file always contains "0000" and nothing else...

Whats the correct way to save data encoding in utf-8 without bom? Thank you

This is my webservice.php:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $data = $_POST["author"] . "\n" . $_POST["title"] . "\n" + $_POST["category"] . "\n" + $_POST["article"];
    $fileName = mb_convert_encoding($_REQUEST["author"], "UTF-8", "auto");
    $data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', "auto");
    file_put_contents($fileName, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    print $data;
}else{
    invalidRequest();
} ?>
```

Comment: Why do you need conversion? If you make the page with the form as UTF8, you should be able to just write to the file exactly what you got.

Comment: A little research shown me that `mb_convert_encoding` does not support `UTF-8` without `BOM`. To get around this issue, you might want to remove the first 3 bytes from that field.

Comment: sorry, I am new to php, can u explain clearer how to remove 3 bytes from the field. I didn't do a conversion at first but the file also contains only "00000" . By the way, I ancoded my form in UTF-8 without Bom. Thanks guys  @fastreload

Comment: @fastreload - what has mb_convert_encoding got to do with data in files, with or without a BOM?

Comment: b/c I read a post here saying that if I want to save a file in utf8, then I have to use mb_convert_encoding

Comment: @kaboom - If you want to save a file in utf-8 and your data isn't in utf-8, then yes, you need to convert it to utf-8, using something like mb_convert_encoding() or iconv()... but the act of conversion using those functions is not directly related to writing the file... and when you do write the file, it doesn't need a bom if the reading program is expecting the data to be utf-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the filename-argument for file_put_contents() , your code will not save anything into a file.

---

**`<edit>`**

Also take a look at this:

```
  + $_POST["category"] . "\n" + $_POST["article"];
  ^                           ^
```

you are using the  mathematical operators + there, so your string will be converted to a Number(0 in that case)

Answer (score 2):

Your form should contain

```
<form ... accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

Then you can write to file without mb_convert_encoding(). But NEVER EVER USE

```
$fileName = $_REQUEST["author"];
```

! Something like

```
$fileName = $author_names[$_REQUEST["author_id"]];
```

should be safe.

Comment: sorry. it doesn't work. Is there anything to do with UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM? Thanks

Comment: Well, the "0000" you mentioned is not a BOM. See [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for what a BOM looks like. I'd try to narrow down the problem by removing unnessary conversions. And the "accept-charset" is needed to tell the browser to send UTF-8, thus no buggy server-side conversion has to occur. Have you tried it with different browsers?